# Firebase does not create a child under ref in database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make an iOS app that stores boys and girls separately in firebase based on the gender they enter. However in the following code when I am trying to create a node, it only creates it if I name the child of ref as "users", doesn't work otherwise.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

//makes a child of ref called user                    
let usersReference = ref.child("users") //PROBLEM IS HERE, IF I NAME IT ANYTHING OTHER THAN USERS, IT DOES NOT SAVE IN THE DATABASE

let uid = user?.uid
let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid!)
newUserReference.setValue(["email": self.emailField.text!])
```

Comment: if your database model of users in Firebase is named "users", then you have to name it "users", otherwise it will save it in another table.

Comment: I do not have anything created in the database, I am trying to create the database model with this command, but if I name it anything other than "users", it doesn't create the table, but creates it if I name it "users"

Comment: How are your realtime database security rules  set?